# Regex preg_match between this {# .... #}

Tags: php, preg-match

I do like to create a preg_match between this 2 string  start here "{#" and ends here "#}";

what is the best way to extract the data between this ?

```
"/{#(.*?)#}/"
```

I have leaner that there is an APP https://www.phpliveregex.com/

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: I tried using str_replace, but was not the right way

Answer (score 0):

```
"/\{\#(.*?)\#\}/g"
```

Also learn regex here http://regex101.com/

---

**Edit:**

Would you share some of your code because it works fine.
Here is a test of the regex

http://regex101.com/r/aC1fT2/1

and here it is in action:

```
 ~ 
 ⚡⚡⚡  more test.php; php test.php 
<?php
//The source code
    $pattern = "/\{\#(.*?)\#\}/";
    $test_string = 
    "
        Lorem Ipsum is simply {#dummy#} text 
        of the printing and typesetting industry. 
        Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's {#standard#} dummy text 
        ever since the 1500s, 
        when an unknown printer took a galley of type 
        and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
        It has survived not only five centuries, 
        but also the leap into electronic typesetting, 
        remaining {#essentially unchanged#}. 
        It was popularised in the 1960s 
        with the release of Letraset sheets 
        containing Lorem Ipsum passages, 
        {#and more recently with desktop publishing software#} 
        like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    ";
    preg_match_all($pattern, $test_string, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
?>
...
//The output
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {#dummy#}
            [1] => {#standard#}
            [2] => {#essentially unchanged#}
            [3] => {#and more recently with desktop publishing software#}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => dummy
            [1] => standard
            [2] => essentially unchanged
            [3] => and more recently with desktop publishing software
        )

)
```

Comment: ` {#
name: Test
filename: Test 1
date: 123
autor:  test
#} `